# How to use deserialized object?

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8

I am serializing and deserializing an Object in C# for Windows 8 Apps.

I am serializing my Object before passing it to the next View, because passing an object throws out exceptions.

function OnNavigatedTo:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
   string XMLString = e.Parameter.ToString();
   var thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString(XMLString, typeof(Channel));
 ....}
```

Deserializing Function:

```
  public static Channel XmlDeserializeFromString<Channel>(string objectData)
    {
        return (Channel)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(Channel));
    }

    public static object XmlDeserializeFromString(string objectData, Type type)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        object result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

[image: Object Content]

I want to access the data in this Object, but something like: thisChannel.Name doesn't work. And I don't know how that I can continue working with this Object.

Comment: var thisChannel = (Channel)XmlDeserializeFromString(XMLString, typeof(Channel)); maybe? Or use the other method available  var thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString(XMLString);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by dropping `var` in this line:

```
 //var thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString(XMLString, typeof(Channel));
 Channel thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString(XMLString, typeof(Channel));
```

and then you will at least get an error when the wrong `object XmlDeserializeFromString()` is selected.

And to be sure you use the right one:

```
 Channel thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString<Channel>(XMLString);
```

Overloading should be used with care and generally not mixed with Type parameters.

Comment: well thanks to this Answer and the comment by @Ric on my Question I was able to solve the Problem. The Solution was to do it like this: Channel thisChannel = (Channel)XmlDeserializeFromString(XMLString, typeof(Channel));

Comment: and now i noticed that this: Channel thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString<Channel>(XMLString); works too ;) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`XmlDeserializeFromString` returns an `object`, which does not have a `Name` property.  You need to either:

1. cast it to the type you want to use it as
2. use the generic method you added which does that:

   ```
   var thisChannel = XmlDeserializeFromString<Channel>(XMLString);`
   ```
3. use `dynamic` to resolve the method name at runtime
4. use reflection to find the `Name` property at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Yes JSON > XML, though you want to stick to XML, use [TCD.Serialization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TCD.Serialization), it offers serialization and deserialization XML and JSON to/from stream & string.

.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

Passing non-primitive types through a navigation parameter will cause your application to crash when it restores from Suspend.

Only ever pass a primitive type as a navigation parameter in a Windows 8 app.

See [SuspensionManager Error when application has more than 1 page in windows 8 XAML/C# app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829716/suspensionmanager-error-when-application-has-more-than-1-page-in-windows-8-xaml/15834249#15834249)

Comment: hey Jon, that's is why i am serializing my Object first. Even I still got Problems with Bitmaps, I put  [XmlIgnore] before the definition of the bitmap image.

Comment: You should still give the video a look.  http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-133