# Serializing Object containing BitmapImage

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, bitmap, xml-serialization

This is a further question about this topic: [How to use deserialized object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444861/how-to-use-deserialized-object/18455591#18455591) I have a Problem with some variables in my class, right now I just put `[XmlIgnore]` infront of the variables wich cannot be serialized, so the serialazation  of the class works for now.

My class looks like this:

```
public class Channel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public BitmapImage Logo { get; set; }
    public string CurrentCoverURL { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public SolidColorBrush Background { get; set; }
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I somehow need to serialize the Bitmapimage and the SolidColorBrush too, so I can pass these informations to my next view.

I found a way to do this([Serialize a Bitmap in C#/.NET to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml)), but this doesn't work for Windows 8 Apps. `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is not available in Windows 8.

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This helped me do the same thing.  Just convert to a byte array first.

http://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/

You can include your image in your JSON payload like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

or you can include the imageUri in your JSON payload like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Int32 PersonId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String ImageUri { get; set; }
}
```

And you can convert your bitmapimage to a byte array like this;

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var btmMap = new WriteableBitmap
            (bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);

        // write an image into the stream
        btmMap.SaveJpeg(ms, bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers that consist of little more than links are discouraged here. Over the long term, links change and then your answer will be useless. Please consider expanding on your answer to include some concrete examples.

Comment: Are you sure this code works?  From reading it, the data in `bitmapImage` isn't actually read.  Only it's dimensions are queried to create a new `WriteableBitmap` with a matching size, then you're saving that just-created `WriteableBitmap` to a byte array but you're never actually reading the data in `bitmapImage`.

Comment: Also, `WriteableBitmap` doesn't have a `SaveJpeg` method.  Are you possibly referencing an extension method in your code that added it? If so, you should include that code as well.  But again, the above code doesn't appear to work in the first place as nothing actually reads `bitmapImage`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to stop serializing *implementation* (such as `BitmapImage`, `SolidColorBrush`, etc), are start serializing *data*. For example, if you want to transfer an image such as a jpg, gif, etc: a `byte[]` works remarkably well, and will be understood by most serializers. If you want to serialize a color - then you have various options:

- an enum
- an RGBA value (could be an `int` or a `string`)

etc. This will work fine on virtually any serializer and platform. Then you simply process that data in the relevant way for your target platform.

Answer (score 0):

*"I found a way to do this(Serialize a Bitmap in C#/.NET to XML), but this doesn't work for Windows 8 Apps. System.Drawing.Bitmap is not available in Windows 8."*

You can use the BitmapImage.StreamSource for saving/CopyTo it to a MemoryStream and converting it to a bytearray